# Python Web scrape: problems with classes

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to scrape the names from real estate agents from this [website](https://woollahra.ljhooker.com.au/our-team).

My code:

```
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"team-details"})

for container in containers:
    agent_name = container.findAll("a", {"class":"team-name_link"})
    name = agent_name[0].text


    print("name: " + name)
```

However, when I run the script, I receive only the first two names, followed by an error message:

```
name: Michael Stavrianos
name: Kristalla Stavrianos
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Toby\Desktop\Webscrape\LjHooker - mark1.py", line 16, in <module>
    name = agent_name[0].text
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I discovered that the first two agent names are under the class "team-name_link", however the rest are under the class "team-name". I am unsure how to scrape the names from the two sets of classes at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you got it wrong, all names are inside the desired tag, but you actually need to be looking for `div`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

html = requests.get("https://woollahra.ljhooker.com.au/our-team").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
containers = soup.findAll("div",{"class":"team-details"})

for container in containers:
    agent_name = container.find("div", {"class":"team-name"})
    name = agent_name.text
    print(name)
```

The above code outputs:

```
Michael Stavrianos
              Licensee



Kristalla Stavrianos
              Principal



Jade Marshall
              Property Management Associate


Emma Phelan
              Property Management Associate


Isabella Marechal - Ross
              Property Management Associate


Victoria Empson
              Property Investment Manager
```